# how to check if a string is in a value in dictionary python

Tags: python

```js
fruit={'apple':'one','banana':'two','orange':'three'}
a='one'
if a in fruit.value():
    print(a,"was found!")
```

When I run this on python it shows:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'value'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary has no element called key(). What you're meant to use is keys() with an s at the end. This is how it should look like:

```python
fruit={'apple':'one','banana':'two','orange':'three'}
a='apple'

if a in fruit.keys():
    print(f"Yes, key: '{a}' exists in dictionary")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check it like this:

```
fruit={'apple':'one','banana':'two','orange':'three'}
a='apple'
if a in fruit:
    print(a,"was found!")
```